# npm start command not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, npm-install

I was having Vs2013 with old Typescript version 1.8 
also I just installed VS 2015 with new typescript version 2.3

while i trying npm start command from my project path  its not working giving below error.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Project\Angular2Demo\Angular2Demo\npm-debug.log
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.` Are you behind a proxy? Can you ping something on the internet (Google)?

Comment: yes i am able to ping google

Comment: I also tried npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm -g cache clean
npm install -g -f angular-cli..but while executing last command npm install -g -f angular-cli. i am getting erros

Comment: npm config get proxy
npm config get https-proxy - Any one can guide me this two commands returing null value?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's either a problem with permission in the folder (try chmod 777 * from inside of the folder) or a problem with the local variable within the system, which is pointing to your previous TS version. try that out and get us back with info.

Comment: HI i can see three tyecript folder due to diff version on VS installed in my pc. when i checked environment variable"PATH" i cant see anything related to NPM or type script?

Comment: if you are going to use the npm start command, I would suggest you to install Typescript globally from npm and then, change the variable path to that version. Your problem will be gone

Comment: I also tried npm uninstall -g angular-cli npm -g cache clean npm install -g -f angular-cli..but while executing last command npm install -g -f angular-cli. i am getting erros

Comment: anything else i have to do guide me with steps ?

Comment: well now I am confused what's your problem exactly, because you were complaining about TS and not about Angular or Angular CLI

Comment: HI..when i using NPM install command i am getting proxy error..So i tried to use below comannd to remove proxy settings npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy also used netsh winhttp show proxy to see any proxy settings but i am getting message 'direct access' no proxy servers. so when i running NPM install command from project folder its trying to execute C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js some how its giving proxy error  any idea?

Comment: i used this command to check proxy settings netsh winhttp show proxy got reply Current WinHTTP proxy settings: Direct access (no proxy server)